# How to control the height of the FlowDocument Zoom Controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, flowdocument

In the following, the zoom controls end up being proportional to the FontSize set in the Expander control:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel>
    <Expander MaxHeight="500" Margin="5" Padding="5" FontSize="40pt" Header="Test Header">
      <FlowDocumentReader ViewingMode="Scroll" >
        <FlowDocument  Foreground="Black" FontSize="18pt">
          <List>
              <ListItem>
                <Paragraph>Test</Paragraph>
              </ListItem>
            </List>
        </FlowDocument>
      </FlowDocumentReader>
    </Expander>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I would like to be able to control the height of the zoom controls independent of settings in the Expander control.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out one way to do it.  Set the FontSize of the FlowDocumentReader.  Then the size of the zoom buttons will depend on the FontSize in the FlowDocumentReader.

Probably not the ideal way to do it, but it works.